# how to detect items count in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm trying to detect list items like `listview.getCount()` in list view but this it in recycler view. so i use this piece of code,

```
int count = 0;
if (adapter != null) {
    count = adapter.getItemCount();
}
```

to detect it. actually it can detect how many items i have in list, but it won't change something in if for example my code

```
adapter = new AssetsAdapter(data_map);
list = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_diperbaiki);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

// LoadMore button
load.setText("Load More");

list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
list.setAdapter(adapter);
int count = 0;
if (adapter != null) {
    count = adapter.getItemCount();
}
Log.d("items", "" + count);
if (count < 9) {
    load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Starting a new async task
        new DiperbaikiFragment.loadMoreListView().execute();
    }
});
```

i want `load` which is button is GONE when the list item less than 9, but it won't happen. please help if there is another way or if i have done something wrong in my code.

Comment: Log.d("items", "" + count) what this line is prints in logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Please check `adapter = new AssetsAdapter(data_map);` , Check the default size of this `data_map` object.

If initially `data_map.size() > 9`, Then below logic is `false`

```
if (count < 9) {
            load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

I think this is the issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the data list in **data_map**. So you simply get the count from the list.

```
int count = data_map.size();
if (count < 9) {
        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

That's it. Hope this will help.